# onclick="confirm()" cancel button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, button

I have grid , in that gird , for particular record I'm keeping active/inactive status.
this is the view of that status

[image]

when I click active button Its showing this alert message.

[image]

but when I click cancel button I cant stop the action which is going to be active status.

this is the html code snippet for this active/inactive buttons

```
   @if (item.Status == true)
                       {
                           <button class="btn btn-xs active btn-primary" data-HEI_ID = "@item.HEI_ID" data-status = "true"  onclick="confirm_active()">Active</button>                       
                            <button class="btn btn-xs inactiveColor btn-default" data-HEI_ID = "@item.HEI_ID" data-status = "false"  onclick="confirm_inactive()">Inactive</button>

                       }

                       else
                       {
                           <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" data-HEI_ID = "@item.HEI_ID" data-status = "true"  onclick="confirm_active()">Active</button>                       
                           <button class="btn btn-xs inactiveColor btn-primary active" data-HEI_ID = "@item.HEI_ID" data-status = "false"  onclick="confirm_inactive()">Inactive</button>

                           }
```

this is script part for the alert message

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirm_active() {
    var retVal = confirm("Are you sure you want to change the status to Active?");
    if (retVal == true) {
        // do stuff
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function confirm_inactive() {
    var retVal = confirm("Are you sure you want to change the status to Inactive?");
    if (retVal == true) {
       // do stuff
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

How can I make workable cancel button

Comment: You're not returning the value in the markup.

Answer (score 5):

You missed the `return` statement in the `onclick` handler. As a additional note its good practice to end the function call with semi-colon

*Change*

```
 onclick="confirm_active()"
```

*To*

```
 onclick="return confirm_active();"
```

Same applies to `confirm_inactive()` as well.

Comment: Hi , thanks for the answer , but I tried this before and it gives me same result , cancel button not working in this approach also

Comment: Give it one more try, debug the code to see if you are returning false. Also make sure you do not have any javascript error, as sometimes wrong spelling of return statement result in unwanted results

Answer (score 0):

If you use onclick function that return any value you must write `return` before function  here is example

```
   @if (item.Status == true)
                       {
                           <button class="btn btn-xs active btn-primary" data-HEI_ID = "@item.HEI_ID" data-status = "true"  onclick="return confirm_active()">Active</button>                       
                            <button class="btn btn-xs inactiveColor btn-default" data-HEI_ID = "@item.HEI_ID" data-status = "false"  onclick="return confirm_inactive()">Inactive</button>

                       }

                       else
                       {
                           <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" data-HEI_ID = "@item.HEI_ID" data-status = "true"  onclick="return confirm_active()">Active</button>                       
                           <button class="btn btn-xs inactiveColor btn-primary active" data-HEI_ID = "@item.HEI_ID" data-status = "false"  onclick="return confirm_inactive()">Inactive</button>

                           }
```

Also you  can write direct confirm in your html

```
                           <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" data-HEI_ID = "@item.HEI_ID" data-status = "true"  onclick='confirm("Are you sure you want to change the status to Inactive?")'>Active</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return value to the element who is creating this event. You are calling a function on click of that element, how element would know the return value of that function. so instead of `confirm_inactive()` you need to use `return confirm_inactive()` in on click.

Using confirm_inactive() is just like

```
function onClick(){
   confirm_inactive()
}
```

where return confirm_inactive() is like

```
function onClick(){
   return confirm_inactive()
}
```

in first case even confirm_inactive() returns something, you will get undefined when you call onClick().
But in second case, when you call onClick(), it calls confirm_inactive() and returns its result.

**This example is just to understand, the problem.**

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Language" charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>University ID</th>
                <th>University Name</th>
                <th>Established Year</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>000001</td>
                <td>Kelum U</td>
                <td>1976</td>
                <td class="privacy">Private</td>
                <td class="status">
                    <button class='btn btn-xs btn-default confirm_active' data-HEI_ID = '@item.HEI_ID' data-status = 'true'>Active</button><button class='btn btn-xs btn-danger active confirm_inactive' data-HEI_ID = '@item.HEI_ID' data-status = 'false'>Inactive</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>000002</td>
                <td>Wiling M</td>
                <td>1977</td>
                <td class="privacy">Public</td>
                <td class="status">
                    <button class='btn btn-xs btn-default confirm_active' data-HEI_ID = '@item.HEI_ID' data-status = 'true'>Active</button><button class='btn btn-xs btn-danger active confirm_inactive' data-HEI_ID = '@item.HEI_ID' data-status = 'false'>Inactive</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
        $(".status .confirm_active").on('click', function(){
            var retVal = confirm("Are you sure you want to change the status to Active?");
            if(retVal == true){
                $(this).removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-primary active');
                $(this).closest('.status').find('.confirm_inactive')
                .removeClass('btn-danger active').addClass('btn-default');
                $(this).closest('tr').find('.privacy').html('Private');
            }
        });

        $(".status .confirm_inactive").on('click', function(){
            var retVal = confirm("Are you sure you want to change the status to Inactive?");
            if(retVal == true){
                $(this).removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-danger active');
                $(this).closest('.status').find('.confirm_active')
                .removeClass('btn-primary active').addClass('btn-default');
                $(this).closest('tr').find('.privacy').html('Public');
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```